# Set Cassandra's replication factor in cassandra.yaml

Tags: configuration, cassandra, cassandra-2.0

I need to configure my single node cassandra with a global replication factor for all keyspaces I've and keyspaces I will create,
AFAIK replication factor can be configured per keyspace or in cassandra.yaml file for all keyspaces.

did anyone try to configure Replication Factor in cassandra.yaml file ? and how ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to configure the replication factor in cassandra.yaml.

This is always done on a per keyspace basis.  Since you only have a single node, you will need to configure a replication factor of 1 for your keyspaces.

Comment: yeah that's what I thought even configuring replication factor in in cassandra.yaml file can be done per keystone too, but what really confuses me this example http://academy.datastax.com/content/you-are-starting-s-new-cassandra-cluster-and